# Programmatic use of Openstack API in C#

Tags: c#, cloud, virtual-machine, openstack

Is it possible to use Openstack API in codes such as C#? I am writing some code and will need to bring up VM instances in Openstack infrastructure. Hence, how do I write a code to fire up instances in Openstack? let me know if another language will do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of using a another language then python, you should use the REST-API of Openstack to interact with an openstack-deployment via HTTP-requests.

See here for example the REST-API documentation for the compute part to control instances: https://docs.openstack.org/api-ref/compute/ and there for your desired case of creating an instance: https://docs.openstack.org/api-ref/compute/?expanded=create-server-detail#create-server

Comment: Thank you for sending the links.